# Notify cursor change without updating ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I'm using a `CursorAdapter` to fill my `ListView`. I get the `Cursor` through a basic `CursorLoader` that gets the data from my `ContentProvider`. Right now, when the `Cursor` is loaded in `onLoadFinished` of my `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`, I call `setNotificationUri()` on the `Cursor` and in my `ContentProvider`, I'm calling `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(MY_CONTENT_URI, null)` whenever a change to the database has occurred.

The desired behaviour is that I can get notified whenever there's new data in the database and provide an option to the user to reload the `Cursor` and repopulate the `ListView`. Any suggestions on how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not work with the standard `CursorLoader`. `CursorLoader` implements its own ContentObserver that is registered on your behalf. When there is a notification on the `Uri`, the loader will automatically force a reload of the cursor.

I see two possibilities:

1. Allow the loader to reload the cursor. In `onLoadFinished` of your `LoaderCallbacks`, you can present the user with the option and only change the cursor in the adapter based on their response.
2. Write your own `CursorAdapter` implementation that offers some hook at the moment it wants to reload the data. You can start by examining the [source code for CursorLoader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/CursorLoader.java) and its superclasses. In particular, the method `onContentChanged`, which is called by the internal ContentObserver, seems like a good place to add this extra behavior that your want.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is notifying another Structure instead of `ListView`, isn't it?

i.e. that would be code to notify a `ListView` with `CursorLoader`

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the old cursor
    // once we return.)       
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // <- Here we notify the change to Adapter
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);   // <- Then we set ListView with Adapter
    dataAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}
```

So, then all you need is overriding `notifyDataSetChanged` Method of your `CursorAdapter`, so that, this Class inherits from `BaseAdapter` and this Class have such a Method. You can perform there in what way and what you notify.

Then you just should replace `ListView` for you want to be notified in the above code.

Before `listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter)` you could call a dialog in order to ask User whether ListView should be populated or not. I'd do it like this.

I hope, that could help you.

Kind Regards.

p.s. I chose `notifyDataSetChanged`, you can use this approach for other notify-Methods, just see whether they are implemented for an Adapter.